# Plotly chart background click event

Tags: javascript, plotly

Is there a way to attach a click event into the background of a Plotly.js chart?

The idea is to let the user click on the chart in order to select the coordinates of a new element. So, it's not just an standard event on the div wrapper, but a specific event that can track the relative coordinates of the selected location.

The [plotly_click event](http://plot.ly/javascript/plotlyjs-function-reference/#using-events) specified in the documentation is only attached to the specific elements (dots, lines, etc) and I couldn't find any way to achieve what I am looking for.

We are migrating from Highcharts, which lets you define a callback for a click event on the [chart](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.events.click) as well as for a click on the [points](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.scatter.events.click).

Is there anything like this in Plotly.js or any way to accomplish it?